# Can I get the value of Sum(amount_sold) from sales table inside the annotate

Tags: python, django, annotate

I'm trying to display a html table that is populated with sum values from the database. I have sum_amount_purchased and sum_total_price_purchased working fine but I am struggling with sum_amount_sold to get this value I need to query the sales table. Is this possible to do this inside an annotate? I want the sum of all sales for the each currency for that user. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Table Below

```
{% for transaction in transactions %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{transaction.currency}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.sum_amount_purchased}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.sum_total_price_purchased }}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.sum_amount_sold}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Transaction model below

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField()
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_per_coin = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, editable=False)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin = self.total_price / self.amount
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+','+self.currency + ', '+str(self.amount)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('transaction-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Sale model below

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    amount_sold = models.IntegerField()
    total_price_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_sold = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sales")
    amount_per_coin_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+','+str(self.amount_sold) + ', '+self.note

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin_sold = self.total_price_sold / self.amount_sold
        super(Sale, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sale-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

View below

```
@login_required
def portfolio(request):

    context = {
        'transactions': Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values('currency').annotate(
            sum_amount_purchased=Sum('amount'),
            sum_total_price_purchased=Sum('total_price'),
            sum_amount_sold=Sum('sales')
        ),
    }
    return render(request, 'webapp/portfolio.html', context, {'title': 'Portfolio'})
```

Comment: How are you calculating the two you do have? Show the view.

Comment: hi @Daniel   have edited to show the view

Comment: Don't post code in contents. Edit your question and post it there.

Comment: @Daniel sorry about that I have edited now and removed code from comment. I'm a bit new to this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the double-underscore syntax to traverse to the field on Sale you actually want to sum - presumably amount_sold:

```
sum_amount_sold=Sum('sales__amoint_sold')
```